При уменьшении окна, окно уменьшается, но сразу возвращается к прежним размерам
using NetMQ;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows;
using System;

namespace anongram
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool isMaximized = false;
        private double previousWidthBeforeMaximize;
        private double previousHeightBeforeMaximize;
        private double previousLeftBeforeMaximize;
        private double previousTopBeforeMaximize;
        private double originalWidth;
        private double originalHeight;
        private double originalLeft;
        private double originalTop;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Добавляем обработчик события изменения размеров окна
            SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;

            // Добавляем обработчик события изменения параметров системы (включая панель задач)
            SystemParameters.StaticPropertyChanged += SystemParameters_StaticPropertyChanged;

            // Добавляем обработчик события Loaded
            originalWidth = Width;
            originalHeight = Height;
            originalLeft = Left;
            originalTop = Top;
        }
        private void MaximizeWindow(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isMaximized)
            {
                // Сужаем окно до изначальных размеров и расположения
                Width = originalWidth;
                Height = originalHeight;
                Left = originalLeft;
                Top = originalTop;

                isMaximized = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // Сохраняем текущие размеры и расположение окна
                previousWidthBeforeMaximize = Width;
                previousHeightBeforeMaximize = Height;
                previousLeftBeforeMaximize = Left;
                previousTopBeforeMaximize = Top;

                // Получаем размеры панели задач
                double taskbarHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;

                // Вычисляем новые размеры окна
                double newWidth = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
                double newHeight = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;

                // Устанавливаем новые размеры и расположение окна
                Width = newWidth;
                Height = newHeight;
                Left = (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - newWidth) / 2 + SystemParameters.WorkArea.Left;
                Top = (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - newHeight) / 2 + SystemParameters.WorkArea.Top;

                isMaximized = true;
            }
        }
        private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isMaximized)
            {
                // Сохраняем текущие размеры и расположение окна
                previousWidthBeforeMaximize = Width;
                previousHeightBeforeMaximize = Height;
                previousLeftBeforeMaximize = Left;
                previousTopBeforeMaximize = Top;

                // Получаем размеры панели задач
                double taskbarHeight = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;

                // Вычисляем новые размеры окна
                double newWidth = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
                double newHeight = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;

                // Устанавливаем новые размеры и расположение окна
                Width = newWidth;
                Height = newHeight;
                Left = (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - newWidth) / 2 + SystemParameters.WorkArea.Left;
                Top = (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - newHeight) / 2 + SystemParameters.WorkArea.Top;

            }
            else if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized && isMaximized)
            {
                // Окно было расширено, а затем пытались сузить его
                isMaximized = false;
            }
        }

        private void SystemParameters_StaticPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Проверяем, было ли изменение в параметрах, связанных с панелью задач
            if (e.PropertyName == "WorkArea" && isMaximized)
            {
                // Вызываем метод MainWindow_SizeChanged для корректной настройки размеров окна
                MainWindow_SizeChanged(null, null);
            }
        }
    }
}

При нажатии первый раз на кнопку, окно расширяется, но когда нажимаю второй раз, окно уменьшается, но сразу возвращается к прежнему расширенному размеру.

А можно вопрос... Зачем это?

А как должно быть? Что именно с окном не так, если вообще весь этот код убрать?

Я собираюсь сделать свою панель задач (как я понял оно так называется, но чтобы было понятнее, сверху панель где есть кнопки свернуть, расширить/сузить окно, закрыть) и вот хочу сделать функции расширить и сузить, но если с расширением всё нормально, то сузить не получается

Если вы про верхнюю панель любого окна, то опять вопрос - зачем? В WPF всякие перетаскивания и прочее делаются парой строк кода, достаточно восстановить WindowChrome. Что касается свернуть/развернуть/закрыть, то это также делается элементарно, а именно установкой WindowState нужного значения, например WindowState = WindowState.Maximized; - это развернуть окно, а WindowState = WindowState.Minimized; - свернуть, ну и т.д. И всеж... Зачем?

Когда я использую WindowState.Maximized; окно расширяется на весь экран и перекрывает панель пуск

А это вы уже что-то нахимичили, либо в Windows, либо в вашем коде. Создайте пустой WPF проект и в конструкторе окна напишите this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;, запустите, посмотрите на результат, должно быть как и у любого другого приложения, до панели пуска. Вот если не верите, сделал этот эксперимент за вас, ну и как видите, у меня окно растянулось и не затрагивает пуск.

Проверил на новом проекте, тоже не работает.

Кажется я понял почему у меня на весь экран, а у вас всё нормально. Потому что у меня стоит  WindowStyle="None", я же делаю сам кнопки

Вот эту проблему и надо вам решать, а не писать свои костыли, которые вызывают совершенно другую проблему, скрывая нужную. Если в лоб решать это, то установите просто один раз окну this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight; и все будет работать как надо. Но у этого решения есть ряд проблем, связаны они с несколькими мониторами. Так что, если вас устраивает это, то используйте, нет - можете задать отдельный вопрос.

Это немного решает мою проблему. Просто при SingleBorderWindow  окно расширяется и не задевает панель пуск где бы оно не было, аthis.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight; подходит только в том случае, если панель пуск находится снизу. И также я хотел сделать, когда окно расширено и мы перемещаем панель пуск, то окно сразу подстраивалось под новое расположение панели.

Советую не заморачиваться с этим. Данный функционал (перемещения панели) убрали из Windows и не думаю, что вернут. Стоит-ли возиться ради того, что уже сейчас является "устаревшим"? Тут конечно ваше право, пишите что хотите и как хотите, но я наверно не стал бы так заморачиваться. В любом случае, я вам советую создать новый вопрос, где будет сказано о том, что при установке WindowStyle="None", свойство WindowState ведет себя не так, как надо. А то в данном вопросе вы совсем не в том направлении двигаетесь, и не понятно ради чего...)
